# Calling a swift file in html page

Tags: html, swift2

Let say if I have a local html page called login.html. In this login.html, I would like to to load the ViewController.swift page or how do I call a swift file in a html page. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Swift. I am with HTML though and this sounds like it's impossible.

Answer (score -3):

For redirect a page you have to put this:
link text

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. :) A tip: avoid answering off-topic questions and very low quality questions, as they will probably be deleted by the community (and your answer with it). See the various topics in the "help" menu for learning how to ask and how to answer on SO. Thanks!